# PHP foreach loop based on specific XML attributes

Tags: php, xml, foreach, html-lists

I'm trying to populate HTML list items with from XML using PHP. It is currently working for a single list, but I can not find a way to load specific lists from an XML containing multiple lists.

This is the working XML file for a single list:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<checklists>
  <list>
    <item>List Item 1</item>
    <item>List Item 2</item>
  </list>
</checklists>
```

This is the php which works for the single list:

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file("checklists.xml");
foreach($xml->checklists->list->item as $value)
{
    echo "<li><a> " . $value . "</a></li>"; 
}
```

I would like to have multiple lists in the XML formatted using attributes, such as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<checklists>
  <list name='List One'>
    <item>List Item 1</item>
    <item>List Item 2</item>
  </list>
  <list name='List Two'>
    <item>List Item 1</item>
    <item>List Item 2</item>
  </list>
</checklists>
```

I have not found a way to run a foreach loop that is specific to the list attribute. I have searched for quite a while on how to do this. I imagine it's quite simple that I'm missing, but I'm lost. Or there may be a better way to achieve this.

**edit:** I'm try to load just one of the lists at a time. So, someone will come to the page only looking for List One and will not want to see List Two. Eventually there will be a lot of lists in this XML file.

Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps you could show an example of how you'd like the generated HTML to look?

Comment: @Phil Just like a regular <ul><li></li></ul> list. Although I'm fine with the HTML part, difficult part is running the foreach loop for only one of the lists. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I hope it will helpful

```
<?php
$xml=simplexml_load_file("checklists.xml");

foreach($xml->list as $value)
{
    foreach($value->item as $val){
        echo "<li><a> " . $val . "</a></li>";
    }
}
```